# How to switch to different layouts and use their widgets from the same activity in android?

Tags: android-layout, android-activity

I have an activity that displays a layout. I would like to go to another layout on the click of a button within the same activity. After going to the next layout, I have to go to a third layout by clicking the button in second layout, that too from tha same activity. I have defined the buttons for each layout in their respective xml files with unique IDs. I am accessig the IDs of all the buttons of all the layouts from the same activity to define "onClick()".

When I define onClick() ofr all the buttons from the same activity, it gives me "NullPointerException" during rum time.

Could anyone give some help as how to accompilish all these things from the same activity?

Answer (score 1):

OnCreate(Bundle icic){

setContentView(R.layout.first_xml);

((Button)findViewById(R.id.button_first).setOnclickListener(new onClickListener(){

```
  secondLayout();
```

});

}

private void secondLayout(){

setContentView(R.layout.second_xml);

((Button)findViewById(R.id.button_second).setOnclickListener(new onClickListener(){

```
  thirdLayout();
```

});

}

private void thirdLayout(){

setContentView(R.layout.third_xml);

((Button)findViewById(R.id.button_third).setOnclickListener(new onClickListener(){

```
 // do work...
```

});

}

But this is not the solution to use code like above... Instead you can use Dialog to achieve your goal......`enter code here`